# I'm trying to create a times table, I'm not sure how to go about it

Tags: java

I have as far as code is:

```
int loopVal;
int addition = 0;
int times_table = 0;
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
………………………("Which times table do you want?");
times_table = user_input.nextInt();
for (loopVal = 1; loopVal < end_value; loopVal++) {
        ………………………………………….;
System.out.println(loopVal + " times " + times_table + " = " + addition);
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to go about it, I don't know what to put in those blank lines or how to make the rest of the code. Could someone please help give me a hand here?

Comment: you need printf statement.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Anyhow for first `......` section you need `System.out.println`

Answer (score 0):

Where do you decide the end_value in the function ? Is it coming as a parameter to the function.
Assuming end_value coming as a parameter to the function,

```
for (loopVal = 1; loopVal <= end_value; loopVal++) 
{
// New addition is calculated with times_table getting multiplied from 1...end_value
addition = times_table * loopVal;   
System.out.println(times_table + " times " + loopVal  + " = " + addition);
}
```

If I have understood what you want, I suppose this will work.